# How can i install PRODSECBUG-2233 patch in Magento 2.2.3?

Tags: magento2, patch

I have download two PRODSECBUG-2233 patch for different Magento version from magento official site.

1) Magento 2.3.0 (PRODSECBUG-2233-2.3.x-2019-07-26-08-35-12.patch)

2) Magento 2.2.3 (PRODSECBUG-2233-2.2.x-2019-07-26-08-35-48.patch)

I have installed PRODSECBUG-2233 patch in Magento 2.3.0 version successfully using below command.

```
patch -p1 < PRODSECBUG-2233-2.3.x-2019-07-26-08-35-12.patch
```

But when i have  try to use same command in Magento 2.2.3, it's not working and show me FAILED in terminal. Please check below.

```
patch -p1 < PRODSECBUG-2233-2.2.x-2019-07-26-08-35-48.patch
...
....
File to patch: vendor/magento/module-sales/Helper/Admin.php
patching file vendor/magento/module-sales/Helper/Admin.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 6 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 31 (different line endings).
Hunk #3 FAILED at 149 (different line endings).
Hunk #4 FAILED at 186 (different line endings).
4 out of 4 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file vendor/magento/module-sales/Helper/Admin.php.rej
```

How can i solve this ? Is this problem in magento .patch file ?

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: were you able to resolve this?